Change taskbar settings without using settings menu?
My organization just updated all computers to use Windows 11. I did so a while back on my own PC, and found all the distracting icons I always remove re-enabled and some new ones added (i.e. search bar, program names/tab headers for open apps, copilot, widgets). Many of these are even more space-filling than in Windows 10, and I would really like to slim down the taskbar.
My organization, by default, disables pretty much every user setting outside of the bare necessities for operating the machine. This includes all of these taskbar settings, as well as the entire control panel and device manager. In the past, I've changed simple settings, such as the desktop background, using batch files, and I also have access to regedit. I'm not experienced with batch script, however, and haven't been able to get this to work here.
Can anyone let help me change this in the registry editor or with a .bat file?
(I've read stackoverflow.com/questions/680705/change-the-taskbar-settings-programmatically and cannot use TaskBarCmd; I assume it'd work on Windows 11, but I can't run .exe files)

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Can't you just ask your IT department if they can turn off these distractions for you?

As your company owns this computer, you need to speak with them regarding this request.
